# Server side design

Tags: java, concurrency, backend

I am new here, and would like to seek for some guidance on my system design.  I am working on a queue system, which will create, update, and remove tickets from my queue base on the client side's request.  I had build a spring boot restful api with that (TicketController).
I want to avoid concurrency issue so I use @Component and synchronized key word to handle any add/remove actions.

TicketController.java

```
@Autowired
    TicketManager ticketManager;

    @RequestMapping(value = "tickets", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ResponseEntity<List<Ticket>> getTickets(
            @RequestParam(value = "device", defaultValue = "") String device) {

        log.info("Ticket GET LIST");

        // get full list of tickets
        List<Ticket> tickets = ticketManager.getTickets();

    }
```

TicketManager.java

```
@Service 
public class TicketManager { 

  // ticket list on memory 
  @Autowired 
private TicketList ticketList = new TicketList(); 

  // actual db services using JPA 
  @Autowired 
private TicketService ticketService; 

/*******************/
/* ticket methods */ 
/*******************/ 
  @Override 
  public Ticket getTicket(BigInteger ticketId) { 
    return ticketList.getTicket(ticketId); 
  } 

  @Override 
  public List<Ticket> getTickets() { 
    return ticketList.getTicketList(); 
  } 

  @Override 
  public synchronized Ticket createTicket(Ticket ticket) throws Exception 
  { 
    // some validation 
    ... 

    // create ticket in DB
    Ticket newTicket = ticketService.createTicket(ticket); 

    // add ticket in memory list. 
    ticketList.add(newTicket); 

    // some other operations ... 
  } 

// some more methods for Ticket update, delete etc. 
  ... 
}
```

TicketList.java

```
@Component 
public class TicketList extends Observable {

private List<Queue> queueList;

@PostConstruct
public void init()
{
    queueList = new ArrayList<Queue>(); 
}

// get a specific queue
public List<Queue> getQueueList()
{
    return queueList;
}

// get a specific ticket
public Ticket getTicket(int id)
{
    Ticket ticket = queueList.stream().flatMap(q -> 
        q.getTicketList().stream().filter(t -> t.getId==id) 
    ).findFirst().orElse(null);
    return ticket;
}

// add ticket
public void add(Ticket ticket)
{
    if (ticket != null)
    {
        Queue queue = ticket.getQueue();

        // find the correct queue to add this ticket
        Queue existingQueue = queueList.stream().filter(q -> q.getId()==queue.getId()).findFirst().orElse(null);

        if (existingQueue != null)
        {
            // ticket list exists, add new ticket to the queue list.
            if (existingQueue.getTicketList() != null)
            {
                // add tickets if not exists in queue already.
                if (!existingQueue.getTicketList().stream().anyMatch(t -> t.getId()==ticket.getId()))
                {
                    existingQueue.getTicketList().add(ticket);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

// update, delete functions, etc
...
}
```

The problems arises when I want to add more restful controllers, e.g. UserController, QueueController, etc.

Since for example if I want to add QueueController rest api class, I will have to enhance this TicketManager to handle the job in order to keep the TicketList object synchronize.

Now, if I want to add another UserController class, should I still keep adding things in the TicketManager class?  User object is also one factor that will trigger something in my ticket update action, should I keep enhancing my TicketManager to handle everything for all restful controllers  or is there any other ways I can implement so that I can cut clear each modules base on different objects?  (e.g. create QueueManager, UserManager to handle specific jobs, but I am afraid my TicketList object would be entered by different thread/instance, and out-sync.)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You have already different controllers(UserController, TicketController) and can call services from these controllers. Why do you need Manager class?

Comment: The reason is that I am trying to keep a container (TicketList class) to store the Tickets and Queues on memory when system loaded.  Whenever people access the container with add/edit/remove, I will notify some other services to handle other job, e.g. SMS_Service to send a notification to users, etc (that is why you see the Ticket list extends Observable class).  So I would like all different controllers using the same sets of data from the container class.  The Manager class provides the entrance for those controllers and also used to handle any business logic and validations.